# how do I execute sh file in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to make a .sh file executable. After editing the permissions of the file to allow executing, I open the file and it to run it and it just opens the text editor. I would like to not have to run it from the terminal every time i want to use it.

Comment: Are you running this in a terminal?  How are you opening it?

Answer (score 3):

if it is an executable, just right click and click execute, run depending on your interface.

if not

```
    chmod a+x /path/to/file.sh
```

then try the same.

you can just type it in terminal too.

```
    /path/to/file.sh
```